# How can I recursively grep through several directories at once?

Tags: grep, search, recursive

I use `grep -r` all the time to find occurrences of a string within files in a given directory:

```
$ grep -r "string" app/assets/javascripts
> app/assets/javascripts/my_file.js: this line contains my string
```

But what if I want to recursively search through **more than one subdirectory** of my current directory? The only way I can think of is to run grep twice:

```
$ grep -r "string" app/assets/javascripts
> app/assets/javascripts/my_file.js: this line contains "string"
$ grep -r "string" spec/javascripts
> app/assets/javascripts/my_file.js: "string" appears here, too.
```

How can I combine the above two `grep` commans into a single line? I don't want to search through every single file in `.`, and `--exclude-dir` isn't practical because there are too many other directories under `.` for me to explicitly exclude them all.

Is this possible?

Comment: Combine find and grep commands. Here is an example http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specifiy multiple directories in `grep`:

```
grep -r "string" app/assets/javascripts spec/javascripts
```

Alternatively - sometimes more useful is list files to grep by `find`, and then grep them, for example

```
find app/assets/javascripts spec/javascripts -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 grep "string"
```

or

```
find app/assets/javascripts spec/javascripts -type f -exec grep -H "string" {} +
```

Comment: Yikes, that was easy! I can't believe I never thought to try that. Thanks.